# Read Json fields in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how can I read using JQuery a Json response like this one: `{"result":{"_id":{"Timestamp":23232323, "Machine:4235245252"}, "Agency":"Crooars",
"City":"New York", "State": "New Jersey"}}`  I want to read `Agency`, `City` and `State`, the other fields are not relevant.
I have tried with something like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: urlPostGraduate,
data: $("#formPostGrad").serialize(), 
success: function (result) {
alert(result.Agency) // returns undefined
alert(result._id.Agency) // it doesn't even show the alert
alert(result["_id"].Agency) //neither
}
```

Comment: Try alert(result.result.Agency);

Comment: don't use `alert()`, use `console.log()`.  then use `console.log(result)`.  Is it what you were expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the root key of your JSON response is `result`, and the parameter to receive the response is also `result`. Thus, if you want to access any info of the response, you need write `result.result.your_key_name`.

For example, you need to write `result.result.Agency` to get the value of `Agency` from the response.

Also, this has nothing to do with jQuery, and is only related to accessing JSON objects in JavaScript.

Comment: Well it has to do with jQuery actually since in old times jQuery did not have intelligent guess to convert response to object and he might have thought something on the line.

Answer (score 1):

The result variable holds the full json response, and you need the result key from within:

```
result.result.Agency
```